# XPages Mobile Controls Not Refreshing Properly

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have created a single-page app, and it seems to be behaving very badly on some page transitions.

I have a View of parent docs, and I then click on a document to load it, OK. I have an 'Add Item' button on the parent to compose a new child doc which will be related to the loaded parent by doc id.

The problem is, when I load the new child doc in edit mode, the previous page is still displayed behind it on screen. I now have a messy jumble of controls, and things get worse from there. If I click the 'Back' button on the child doc, I get the background page back at the parent doc page, but now the child doc is still loaded in the foreground in edit mode. If I hit back again, it goes to a parent form with no doc loaded.

I use the setting resetContent="true" on all pages, and my command to 'Add Item' is:

```
<xe:moveTo targetPage="ItemPage" forceFullRefresh="true" saveDocument="true"></xe:moveTo>
```

I have also tried with:

```
<xe:moveTo targetPage="ItemPage" forceFullRefresh="true" saveDocument="false"></xe:moveTo>
```

What am I doing wrong? This is Domino 8.5.3FP3 with Upgrade Pack 1.

OK, here's the button code in the page heading:

```
<xe:djxmHeading id="ReqHeading" label="Requisition" back="Back" moveTo="viewAllRequisitions">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:button value="Add Item" id="actionFacetButton1" xp:key="actionFacet">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:actionGroup>
                        <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
                        <xp:executeScript script="#{javascript:sessionScope.RequisitionID = document1.getDocument().getUniversalID();}">
                        </xp:executeScript>
                        <xe:moveTo targetPage="ItemPage" forceFullRefresh="true" saveDocument="true"></xe:moveTo>
                    </xp:actionGroup>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xe:djxmHeading>
```

and here's the new child doc page:

```
<xe:djxmHeading id="ItemHeading" label="Add Item" back="Back" moveTo="RequisitionPage">
</xe:djxmHeading>
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Item">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:label value="Job Number:" id="labelSubject1"></xp:label>
<xp:inputText id="txtSubject" value="#{document1.JobNumber}">
</xp:inputText>
<xp:br />
<xp:label value="Item Description: " id="lblDescription"></xp:label>
<xp:inputText id="txtDescription" value="#{document1.Description}"></xp:inputText>
<xp:br />
<xp:label value="Quantity: " id="lblQuantity"></xp:label>
<xp:inputText id="txtQuantity" value="#{document1.Quantity}" defaultValue="1" maxlength="3" size="3"></xp:inputText>
<xe:tabBar barType="segmentedControl" id="tabBar1">
    <xe:tabBarButton id="tabBarButton1" label="Submit">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xe:this.action>
                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
            </xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:tabBarButton>
    <xe:tabBarButton id="tabBarButtonEdit" label="Edit" rendered="#{javascript:!document1.isEditable()}">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit" var="document1">
                </xp:changeDocumentMode>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:tabBarButton>
</xe:tabBar>
```

OK, I have given up on the single-page app for now as I find it does not refresh properly on creating any new docs. This seems to be broken as far as I can tell.

I am now trying to use multiple pages, but when I use a new xpage for the moveTo target, I get an error "destination view not found: null. Is this supposed to work?

Comment: The syntax of your `moveTo` action looks correct, but outside of the context of the surrounding components, it's impossible to be certain. Post as much of the source code as you can without violating any disclosure agreements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM answered this for me via a support ticket. The solution is to use transitionType="slide" on the moveTo.

This is the default and is supposed to be an optional parameter, but if it is omitted, the refresh leaves garbage all over the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use seperate xpages in mobile application as when you move from one mobile page to other this navigation needs to happen inside single application page control. The page you specifying for going back should be mobile page inside single application page control.

I am also facing the same issue the the pages are not getting refreshed when launched.
Ihave to refersh the browser manually then it works and show proper data